# Recursive Function Will not go into return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am using react, redux, redux thunk, and axios to get a random image from reddit using their api. If the image extensions is gifv or the domain is not in bounds I want to call the function recursively. However when I call the function recursively  it will not go into the return statement. I am assuming this has something to do with the promises but I am not sure.

```
export function fetchData(){

    let ran = randomNumber();
    return(dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddits[ran]}/random.json`)
        .then((res) => {
            let post = res.data[0].data.children[0].data;
            if(post.domain === 'i.redd.it' || post.domain === 'i.imgur.com') {
                let imageURL = post.url;
                if(imageURL.split()[3] !== 'gifv'){
                    dispatch(GetImageFromSubSuccess(imageURL))
                }else{
                    return fetchData();
                }
            }else {
                return fetchData();
            }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}
```

Comment: If `fetchData` is one of your redux actions, which I am assuming it is, you have to call dispatch with it. `dispatch(fetchData())`

Comment: @MaxBaldwin fetchData is not one of the redux actions. Instead this is

Comment: @MaxBaldwin export function GetImageFromSubSuccess(url){
    return{
        type: 'GET_IMAGE_FROM_SUB',
        imageUrl: url
    }
}

Comment: thunk should support dispatch(fetchData())

Comment: shouldn't it be: 
                    return dispatch(GetImageFromSubSuccess(imageURL))

Comment: @JeffEdmo follow what Shishir and MRsa mentioned. You need to wrap the proper function in your `dispatch` thunk

Answer (score 0):

The problem making it hard to express recursion is that your code returns `dispatch => ...` function. You need to define the separate async recursive function to handle I/O, and then wrap it to the `dispatch => whatever`.

```
export function fetchData(){
    return(dispatch) => (
        doRecursiveIO().then( imageURL => dispatch( GetImageFromSubSuccess(imageURL) ) );
    )
}
```

Then, it becomes easier to define the recursive promise function.

```
function doRecursiveIO(){
    let ran = randomNumber();

    return axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddits[ran]}/random.json`)
        .then( res => {
            let post = res.data[0].data.children[0].data;

            if(post.domain === 'i.redd.it' || post.domain === 'i.imgur.com') {
                let imageURL = post.url;
                if(imageURL.split()[3] !== 'gifv'){
                    return imageURL;
                }else{
                    return doRecursiveIO();
                }
            }else {
                return doRecursiveIO();
            }
        });
}
```

You can use recursion with asynchronous I/O in a very straightforward way if you would use [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). 
`async`/`await` makes promise code looks like a regular synchronous code, so it's easy to use all the regular techniques like iteration or recursion. Of course, anything which is written with async/await can be rewritten with raw promises (that's what babel or typescript would do having "es5" or "es6" as a target).

```
async function doRecursiveIO(){
    let ran = randomNumber(),
        res = await axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddits[ran]}/random.json`);

    let post = res.data[0].data.children[0].data;

    if(post.domain === 'i.redd.it' || post.domain === 'i.imgur.com') {
        let imageURL = post.url;
        if(imageURL.split()[3] !== 'gifv'){
            return imageURL;
        }else{
            return await doRecursiveIO();
        }
    }else {
        return await doRecursiveIO();
    }
}
```

Something like that. I didn't check the code above and wrote it to illustrate the idea.